# MySQL Left Join With And Condition To Same Column

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

I have tables like this:

```
tbl_product
===========
product_id (PK)

tbl_product_attribute
=====================
pro_attr_id (PK)
pro_attr_pro_id (FK to tbl_product)
pro_attr_attr_opt_id(FK to tbl_attribute_option)
```

Now, I would like query Products which have 2 attributes in the `tbl_product_attribute`.

Example like :

```
SELECT "p".* 
FROM "tbl_omx_product" "p" 
LEFT JOIN "tbl_omx_product_attribute" "proAttr" ON "proAttr".pro_attr_pro_id = p.product_id 
WHERE 
    (pro_attr_attr_opt_id LIKE '%1759%' ) AND 
    (pro_attr_attr_opt_id LIKE '%1776%' )
GROUP BY "p"."product_id";
```

So I'd like to get Products that has exactly 2 values at `tbl_omx_product_attribute`, which is 1759 & 1776.

But query like above won't show any result unless I use relation `OR` instead of `AND`.

The question what is the query to retrieve Products that have 2 values at the tbl_product_attribute ? thank you

Comment: Using a left join are you expecting returned result set to contain null values also? can you show a sample output

Comment: if you know both ids, than why are you using LIKE in where clause. you can use IN (1759,1776)

Comment: @Harry Nope, I'm expecting only results that has value 1759 & 1776. So for example Product 1 has both of the values but Product 2 only has 1759, than I'd like to get the Product 1 only.

Comment: @devpro Using IN will return result which is the same like using relation 'OR'. What I want is Products that have both of the values.

Comment: Then you should be using the = instead of LIKE to match for those values. If you are not expecting null rows then why are you not using an inner join?

Comment: Code Monk's solution is just about there, but if you're still struggling, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: What's wrong with the solution I posted? I think we are all misunderstanding you. Maybe @Strawberry is right, provide more information.

Comment: Thank you @caiohamamura, I have chosen your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you, but if you want the product to have both attribute options you can query:

```
SELECT "p".* 
    FROM "tbl_omx_product" "p" 
    JOIN "tbl_omx_product_attribute" "proAttr1" 
        ON "proAttr1".pro_attr_pro_id = p.product_id 
            AND "proAttr1".pro_attr_attr_opt_id LIKE '%1759%'
    JOIN "tbl_omx_product_attribute" "proAttr2" 
        ON "proAttr2".pro_attr_pro_id = p.product_id 
             AND "proAttr2".pro_attr_attr_opt_id LIKE '%1776%'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get products which have two attributes:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM tbl_omx_product p 
LEFT JOIN tbl_omx_product_attribute proAttr ON proAttr.pro_attr_pro_id = p.product_id 
GROUP BY p.product_id
having count(*)=2;
```

You can filter data as per your required output by just adding where clause.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM tbl_omx_product AS p 
LEFT JOIN  tbl_omx_product_attribute AS proAttr ON  p.product_id = proAttr.pro_attr_pro_id
WHERE 
    (pro_attr_attr_opt_id LIKE '%1759%' ) AND 
    (pro_attr_attr_opt_id LIKE '%1776%' )
GROUP BY p.product_id;
```

Comment: Actually this is the query which I post on my question, which is not working unless the relation use 'OR' instead of 'AND'.